# How do i set first-child active in php loop

Tags: javascript, php, loops

im trying to Loop my accordion with a loop, 
but now my active state ist on all li's.

```
    $(function() {
    // (Optional) Active an item if it has the class "is-active"    

    $(".accordion > .accordion-item.is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideDown();

    $(".accordion > .accordion-item").click(function() {
        // Cancel the siblings
        $(this).siblings(".accordion-item").removeClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideUp();
        // Toggle the item
        $(this).toggleClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideToggle("ease-out");
    });
});
```

My Php

```
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul class="accordion">
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li class="accordion-item is-active">...
```

Comment: on load the first item should have active state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a counter, or a boolean for the first iteration. Without changing much of your code, here is a possible solution:

```php
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul class="accordion">
        <?php $isFirst = true; ?>
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li class="accordion-item <?= $isFirst ? 'is-active' : '' ?>"></li>
        ...
        <?php $isFirst = false; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
```

You could also use a for loop and check for the first index.